# postgres query to return missing data?

Tags: postgresql

postgres newbie here.

I have almost sequential data in a table - e.g.column data

seq 
1
2
4
5
7

I am trying to write a query that returns the missing sequential numbers - eg 3,6 in this case.  Not having much joy.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to construct the full sequence, then join back to your table to filter out the existing values:

```
SELECT seq FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(MIN(seq), MAX(seq)) FROM t
) s (seq)
LEFT JOIN t USING (seq)
WHERE t.seq IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! much more elegant than what I was constructing.